# Storing an array using update_metadata

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Have a custom taxonomy "guest" with extra fields.

```
    foreach ($extra_fields as $field => $display) { ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="<?php echo $field;?>"><?php echo $display;?></label></th>
    <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $field;?>" id="<?php echo $field;?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php   
    }
```

There are 10 extra fields per taxonomy.  Can I / should I save these as an array so each "guest" has 1 entry in the guestmeta table instead of 10 entries?  Retrieval of the data is also a concern.

```
update_metadata('guest', $term_id, 'guest_meta', array($field1 => $value1, $field2 => $value2));
```

vs

```
foreach($extra_fields as $field => $value){
  update_metadata('guest', $term_id, $field, $value);  }
```

Comment: You are presenting a choice between two valid approaches without any criteria to choose by. Simply put - either works. Which to go with depends on specific needs of the project.